# how to download file from SharePoint library with static name in SPFX react?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-library, react-webpart, file-download

I want to download my file with a specific name from SharePoint library using SPFX react.

`<div key={index}><a  download="" >{item.name}</a></div>`
(I am using anchor tag for downloading file)

I used the above code but this doesn't help me. Someone please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set following URL in `src` attribute of anchor tag as `https://<yourdomain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<yoursite>/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=<document-URL>`

```
<a  src="https://<yourdomain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<yoursite>/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=<document-URL>" >{item.name}</a>
```

Comment: this code is working for downloading a file but I also want to give a static name to this file. Could you please help me how can  I change the name of the file ?

Comment: Do you mean that downloaded file must have same name doesn't matter what is the name of that file in document library?